# Why does this docker and flask app give NameError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras, google-cloud-platform

I am following the example [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploy-your-first-deep-learning-model-on-kubernetes-with-python-keras-flask-and-docker-575dc07d9e76). 
I am running the app.py from the example. I change its imports from:

```
from keras.xx
```

to:

```
from tensorflow.keras.xx
```

to fix an error and I downgraded tensorflow to 1.15 to fix another.

I run it thus:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 keras-app
```

but it keeps crashing with:

```
2020-01-23T11:21:10.764365528Z   File "app.py", line 85, in <module>
2020-01-23T11:21:10.764369389Z     tensorflowapp.run(host='0.0.0.0')
2020-01-23T11:21:10.764372622Z NameError: name 'tensorflowapp' is not defined
```

code snippets:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
model = None
```

...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
print(("* Loading Keras model and Flask starting server..."
    "please wait until server has fully started"))
load_model()
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I am new to docker and flask so I'd appreciate any pointers on what I am missing.
I am running this on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is `tensorflowapp`. It should only be `app` in `app.run()` but somehow it is receiving `tensorflowapp` added before `app.run()`. You need to look if you are accidently writing `tensorflow` somewhere in your code/ execution commands.

Comment: What was I thinking?! Much obliged! FYI: the app.py on GCP had `tensorflowapp`, the one locally did not.